# Can an iOS app compiled with iOS 7 run on iPad1

Tags: ios, ipad

Can an iOS app compiled with iOS 7 and with deployment target iOS 5.0, run on an iPad1? I do not have an iPad1 to verify this myself currently. Hence, appreciate if anyone can help answer this.

Comment: It should work, but you should find someone with a real device to run that test on real hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work.
You can verify this by installing the iOS 5.0 simulator. (Settings->downloads tab).